# Treat spaces as spaces after n column

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

How to run bash `column` command that after n columns it treats spaces as spaces and not as a separator?

Input:

```
field1 field2 field3 field 4 with spaces
foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4
bar1 bar2 bar3 bar 4 with spaces
```

Output:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
field1  field2  field3  field 4 with spaces
foo1    foo2    foo3    foo4
bar1    bar2    bar3    bar 4 with spaces
```

Maybe replace spaces with other char before the `column` command and after that replace it again with spaces? `awk` or `sed` might be the right tool for this, but I'm not too familiar with them.

Any help is appreciated! Please, don't shoot me down. This is my first question here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another awk that replaces first 3 spaces with a tab:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=3; ++i) sub(/ +/, "\t")} 1' file
```

```
field1  field2  field3  field 4 with spaces
foo1    foo2    foo3    foo4
bar1    bar2    bar3    bar 4 with spaces
```

Comment: This also worked great with piping this to `column -ts $'\t' -N 'col1,col2,col3,col4`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
$ cat t
field1 field2 field3 field 4 with spaces
foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4
bar1 bar2 bar3 bar 4 with spaces

$ cat t | sed -E 's/^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) (.+)$/\1\t\2\t\3\t\4/g'
field1  field2  field3  field 4 with spaces
foo1    foo2    foo3    foo4
bar1    bar2    bar3    bar 4 with spaces
$
```

Answer (score 0):

How about building another variable, here `s4` to cause confusion:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
}
{
    for(i=4;i<=NF;i++)
        s4=s4 (s4==""?"":" ") $i
    print $1,$2,$3,s4
    s4="" 
}' file
```

Output:

```
field1  field2  field3  field 4 with spaces
foo1    foo2    foo3
bar1    bar2    bar3    bar 4 with spaces
```

If there are multiple spaces `like   this`, you need to set `FS=" "`.

Comment: Piping this to `column -ts $'\t' -N 'col1,col2,col3,col4` doing the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using awk and the example data in a file "spaces", while still utilising column:

```
awk '{ printf $1":"$2":"$3":";
for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) 
    { if (i != NF) { printf $i" " 
      } 
      else { printf $i 
      } 
    } 
    printf "\n" 
    }' spaces | column -t -s":"
```

Use awk to separate the first four fields with ":" and then pipe through to column using ":" as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'y/ /\t/;s/\t/ /4g' file
```

Translate all spaces to tabs and then replace the 4th tab and thereafter with spaces.

If you prefer a kind of symmetry:

```
sed 's/ /\t/g;s/\t/ /4g' file
```